# How much faster is passing a string versus object isolate scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is faster/more performant, passing an object in through isolate scope, or passing an id through a directive and retrieving the resource inside the controller and not putting the whole thing on the scope.

IE. the diff between

```
<my-directive resource="resource"></my-directive>
```

with the DDO:

```
    scope: {
        resource: '=' 
    }
```

and then using the object directly from the scope

OR

```
<my-directive resource-id="{{resource.id}}"></my-directive>
```

With a DDO like:

```
{scope: resourceId: '@'}
```

And a ctrl that somewhat looks like this (assuming a method to get the resource exists through another fn):

```
let resource = ResourceStorage.get($scope.resourceId);
```

OR is there no difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shomz mentions, passing the Object reference should be faster. It involves handling a single value (as in, the reference, representing where the Object is), where-as passing the ID requires actually accessing the ID every time, and then using that to some how find the Object.

Another concern with the by-id method is that you now depend on your Service for finding the Object. You're also depending on storing the id->Object state in your Service, which should typically be avoided. That's a separate concern from your question, however.

So back to the question:

Here's a JSFiddle that tests and times both scenarios (you will need your console open to see the timings): http://jsfiddle.net/e10ha2ey/1/

The test renders 1500 items, and has buttons that you can use to switch how the items are bound. It starts a timer immediately, and ends it after 10 $digest cycles.

I simplified the by-id side so that instead of using a service to find the Object, it's simply grabbing it from the Array stored on its `$parent` (this isn't safe, should not be done in production code - assuming things about the `$parent` is a bad idea.) This way should actually be faster than a Service function, since it avoids extra function calls, and instead just hops through the Object, and grabs the array's item at index id.

Even still, the pass-by-reference is faster. For me, it tends to be about 10% faster, in this particular test.

Most importantly, the pass-by-reference code is significantly cleaner! I believe that this should be the more important consideration in this particular case.

Comment: Doesn't passing by reference create a watch which ends up being slower on large objects if you have, let's say, 4000 objects?

Comment: Both create watchers. By reference will *not* watch every property on the Object. It watches just the reference. You can try to imagine Object comparison in JS as (this is a simplification) basically comparing memory addresses. So it does a comparison similar to  `{} === {}` (which returns `false`, because the two Objects are different / held in different memory addresses).

Comment: But if you want a test, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/e10ha2ey/3/ . In this version each of the objects has 53 properties. The Reference version is still faster, by the same amount as before. It doesn't watch every property separately. In that example, you can open the console and view it for yourself. 1500 Objects, each with 53 properties, running 10 digests. Reference is still a little faster. Also, the difference is still small enough that code clarity (the simpler solution) is better.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to easily compare the performance of the two.

The common sense says that **passing a copy of the resource ID**, then fetching the resource using that ID should be a little slower - if nothing else, it has those two instructions, one primitive object and one function more in comparison to just **passing the object reference**.

---

> How much faster is passing a string versus object isolate scope?

If the code is any good, it should never be faster. It's a matter of passing by reference vs. passing by value (plus doing more, in this case), and passing by reference is **always** faster.

Comment: Not sure that I follow that the common sense holds. Each $digest cycle the pass-by-reference will compare the Object reference to the old Object reference. The pass-by-resource-id (with `{{resource.id}}`) will actually try to reach into the resource, grab the id property, and compare that to its cached/previous value every $digest cycle. So it might actually be backward.

Comment: @DRobinson, it could be the opposite, yes, depending on how optimized the digest cycle is. But passing something by a reference is always faster than passing it by value because in the latter, a new object is created. Not to mention the object look-up function which has to be slower than interacting with internal objects.

Comment: Oops, I read your answer backward. I thought you were saying passing the reference would be _slower_ than the id. Yeah, I was trying to say that by-reference is faster, so I guess I actually ended up agreeing with you... Oops, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @DRobinson Hehe, no problem! :)